# PHP if in foreach gives object

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems listing some products with Laravel.
I want to get products that user has permission to, and that works fine, until I want to foreach products that had sales, then array is transforming to object with key.

So here is an example:

```
$user_id = Auth::guard('api')->id();
$getUserProducts = Products::where('user_id', $user_id)->with('product.images')->distinct()->get();
```

This is how I'm getting products. And here is foreach

```
foreach ($getUserProducts as $key => $product){
                $find_product = ProductAgent::getProductSales($product['product']['id']);
                $sales = $find_product['sales'];

                        $user[$key]['id'] = $product['product']['id'];
                        $user[$key]['slug'] = $product['product']['slug'];
                        $user[$key]['image'] = $product['product']['images'][0]['image_url'];
                        $user[$key]['stats'] =  $find_product;
                        $user[$key]['type'] = $product['product']['type'];
  
            }
```

And in that case everything is ok and data is given as an array.

```
[
{
        "id": "372f49f3-cc54-4663-b3b8-90083b891849",
        "slug": "d",
        "image": "d.jpg",
        "sales": {
            "sales": 11,
            "avarage_price_per_pcs": "5877.45",
            "amount": "64652.00"
        },
        "type": "product"
    },
    {
        "id": "675d183b-a277-4e39-a1df-df8dc35d472b",
        "slug": "s",
        "image": "s.jpg",
        "sales": {
            "sales": 4,
            "avarage_price_per_pcs": "764.70",
            "amount": "3058.80"
        },
        "type": "accessory"
    }
]
```

So If I want to add if statement to check if there is any sales I have to do it like:

```
                   $sales = $find_product['sales'];
                    if($sales){
                        $user[$key]['id'] = $product['product']['id'];
                        $user[$key]['slug'] = $product['product']['slug'];
                        $user[$key]['image'] = $product['product']['images'][0]['image_url'];
                        $user[$key]['sales'] =  $find_product;
                        $user[$key]['type'] = $product['product']['type'];
                    }
```

And data is given like:

```
{
"5": {
        "id": "66ede1cf-470a-4800-81f7-e39ac2f34d43",
        "slug": "d",
        "image": "d.jpg",
        "sales": {
            "sales": 16,
            "avarage_price_per_pcs": "775.54",
            "amount": "12566.01"
        },
        "type": "product"
    },
    "11": {
        "id": "372f49f3-cc54-4663-b3b8-90083b891849",
        "slug": "s",
        "image": "s.jpg",
        "sales": {
            "sales": 11,
            "avarage_price_per_pcs": "5877.45",
            "amount": "64652.00"
        },
        "type": "product"
    }
}
```

And this response is a problem, I have no idea how to fix it. I tried to add else statement and it's giving array again, but I don't want to show products that had no sales.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: "this response is a problem" - what does that mean? What have you tried to filter out sales you want to filter out?

Comment: If you just want those records with sales, add this to the database query and you don't need to worry about the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly, you can use `toArray` method:

```
$getUserProducts = Products::where('user_id', $user_id)->with('product.images')->distinct()->get();

$array=$getUserProducts->toArray();
```

Also if you want get without sales products, I assume you have sales method and that provide relation.

```php
Products::where('user_id', $user_id)->doesntHave('sales')->distinct()->get();
```

And the exact opposite, which products have sales

```php
Products::where('user_id', $user_id)->has('sales')->distinct()->get();
```

**Note:** eloquent associate everything, this will return you a lot of advantage in the future, first of all you need to write the relations between the objects.

Be careful,

that is your code:

```php
foreach ($getUserProducts as $key => $product){
                $find_product = ProductAgent::getProductSales($product['product']['id']);
                $sales = $find_product['sales'];

                        $user[$key]['id'] = $product['product']['id'];
                        $user[$key]['slug'] = $product['product']['slug'];
                        $user[$key]['image'] = $product['product']['images'][0]['image_url'];
                        $user[$key]['stats'] =  $find_product;
                        $user[$key]['type'] = $product['product']['type'];
  
            }
```

May this code will cause n+1 problems, avoid as such things.

Comment: Please share more details. How does the given code ensure that products without sales are not returned?

Comment: you can use doesntHave() relation on laravel  for as such things ...

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain all such details

Comment: ı did, also ı added more detail for performance as n+1  problem

Answer (score 0):

it's because your array key is not continuous, so it will return object instead of array, you can force PHP return array using [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) method:

```
array_values($user);
```